# Power supply design pattern with various capacitors

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, design

I'm seeing the following pattern for power supplies on the board I'm working on:

[image]

What is the purpose of the capacitors? Why are they of different values? What is the purpose of the design pattern?

Comment: Is it an FPGA board?

Comment: @OliGlaser: Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

stevenh already said it pretty good, but most likely they are **decoupling** capacitors.

Decoupling capacitors, or **bypass** capacitors, are capacitors meant to smooth power flow into specific parts of the circuit or into specific ICs.  Changing power demands will create a "sag" on the power supply as it changes to meet output current demands.  This pulls down the voltage. These capacitors will act as "local storage" to the load during a transient event that effectively masks the sag on the power supply to the load being bypassed/decoupled.

In a very dumb downed way, think of it like a pipe.  One end is your power supply, and the other end is your load.  The power supply adjusts itself to supply what the load is demanding.  If the load changes, it might temporarily take enough water (power) out of the pipe to the point where the pipe isn't entirely full.  The pipe not being full is the equivalent of your voltage sagging.  This is what happens all the time on a power supply... load changes, and the voltage sags slightly as the power supply tries to supply enough current to meet demands... then eventually the voltage comes back up once the power supply has changed its output current to meet demands.

Now, a decoupling capacitor is like adding a big tank on **top** of the pipe.  When the pipe is full... the capacitor can't empty any of its water out.  However, when the load gets big enough and the power supply can't supply it quick enough... the tank lets some of its water out to keep the pipe full until the power supply can supply the given current.

As far as why they are different values, different parts of the circuit will require different amounts of power.  Usually you'll see big caps (in the tens of microfarads, in this case, those big 100uF ones) near the power supply output itself... I usually see this referred to as "bulk"... this is for really big transients that pull a lot of power.  Smaller values are for things with smaller current draws.

There's also some math behind the capacitance, I believe, in regards to how fast the capacitor can give up its energy for a transient event.  Smaller capacitance being better for high-frequency transients, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but -1.  I get really tired of reading descriptions of decoupling caps that completely ignore the signal return path issue. Fix it and I'll change it to a +1.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't actually know the physics/math/theory behind capacitors and signal return paths.  I'll accept the -1 on the fact that we're all here for technically-accurate answers to our questions... but I'll point out that if we always admonished the not 100% accurate answers, we'll probably never get to a point where people know the information that they were -1'd for originally about not knowing.  Maybe you should answer and point out my mistakes, not just -1 me?  That benefits everyone.

Comment: I was being unfair.  I removed my -1, but didn't give you a +1.  My pet peeve is that people frequently spread misinformation about decoupling caps.  In fact, none of the current answers to this Q are completely valid (and some are way off) and I don't feel like giving everyone a -1.  I also don't feel like answering the Q directly, as I'm currently trying to figure out how to write on my other pet peeve:  misinformation about signal termination.  But your comment about "put up or shut up" is completely valid, hence me removing the -1.

Comment: Seriously, though... post something up.  I'm not going to stop telling people what I think I know if I believe it to be reasonably true... so the only way to stop me from spreading misinformation (if I am) is to inform me what's wrong.  Same goes for the other posts.  I don't think you need to give a dissertation on decoupling capacitor theory to give people useful tidbits of knowledge. :)  Plus, I want to know if I'm wrong... as I'm sure other people do, too.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes decoupling capacitors for *different* components are shown all in one place (not ideal IMHO as you can't tell at a glance what they belong to), but since it's an FPGA board it's pretty safe to assume they are all dedicated to the FPGA (i.e. *one* component) which makes the answer a bit different from "general decoupling" (e.g. lowish frequency - just stick a 100nF cap on each component... this is the same idea, just a bit more involved due to the higher performance)

Real capacitors are not ideal, they have inductive and resistive properties also. This means that performance of different types varies over different frequencies.

The reason you see capacitors paralleled like this (assuming here that they are all used for the same component - e.g. FPGA, not for decoupling separate components in different parts of the board) is to keep the impedance down over a wide range of frequencies (preferably all the frequencies involved in your design)
Why don't we use one large capacitor? Because of the different frequency performances outlined above. With some high performance components (many gates switching at high speeds) one or two capacitors per rail isn't enough.
A capacitor will decrease in impedance as the frequency rises, until it reaches it's **self resonant frequency**, at which point the impedance will rise and it will look inductive. From this we can see that the package inductance is key to the capacitors useful frequency range.

If we take a couple of real examples:

This [33uF Vishay electrolytic](http://uk.farnell.com/vishay-bc-components/mal203851339e3/capacitor-radial-50v-33uf/dp/1834148) gives a equivalent series inductance (ESL) of 13nH, so the SRF will be:

1/(2pi * sqrt(13-9 * 33e-6)) = 243kHz.

Less than 1MHz - this will be completely unsuitable for the higher frequencies.

To look at a typical 0603 100nF ceramic capacitor with an ESL of =< 2nH:

1 / (2pi * sqrt(2e-9 * 100e-9)) = 11.25MHz

You can get "specialised" capacitors with more than two leads (e.g. 6, 8, 10, etc) to reduce ESL (inductors in parallel = less inductance), with SRFs of more than a GHz. The [Murata LLL range](http://uk.farnell.com/murata/lll185r70j224ma01l/capacitor-0306-220nf-6-3v-x7r/dp/1294638) is an example:

[image: Murata LLL]

It's easy to see the difference the package inductance makes (and also the SRF points). To help visualise things, take a look at this graph from an excellent [Xilinx app note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp623.pdf) (which goes into much more detail than is possible here):

[image: Decoupling]

You can see by paralleling a range of values with SRFs spaced at even intervals, we achieve a low impedance over a wide range. This is critical in high frequency digital design. Note that the lower the value, the more capacitors are needed to achieve an adequate amount of capacitance - this is why you (usually) see more of the lower values. Note that the inductance is what matters, so if you can find a larger capacitance with the same package inductance then use it (If a 100uF cap with 10pF inductance life would be much easier)
In general, the smaller the capacitance though, the smaller the package/inductance can be (unless you use more leads like the LLL series mentioned above) but it makes sense to use the maximum capacitance per package size.
Solid power and ground planes also contribute to the distributed capacitance and make short return paths easier, so they also become a very good idea (read just about essential) in such circuits.

Answer (score 6):

They all belong on a different place of your PCB. This way of drawing is sometimes done for the many decoupling capacitors on a digital board to avoid cluttering the already complex wiring even more, but it's a Bad Habit™.

Especially decoupling capacitors should be drawn where the belong: close to the pins. So that the PCB layout man also know they should be physically close as well. Now one of the 4.7 µF or 470 nF is probably needed close to a regulator's output to keep it stable, and you don't know which one.

Comment: Yes.  Also, this may have been done to reduce ESR by using a greater number of capacitors in parallel.  Fortunately ,the caps a have designators.  So, a question to the O.P. is: where are these caps (with respect to other components and each-other) on the actual board (or layout)?